# Convert iOS device token string back to Data

Tags: swift, push-notification

I want to convert a device token string back into the Data format that was originally given to me through this method:

```swift
func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data
)
```

In this function I'm getting the `String` from `deviceToken` with

```swift
// cd414ecaf22687b31b602cec11c7c4d797ead5cfece5fc59321e7ac35e36d4c1
let token = deviceToken.map { String(format: "%02.2hhx", $0) }.joined()
```

And I save this token for later use in a notification handler SDK that I'm using.
The problem is that this SDK wants the Data representation of the token and not the string.

So how can i convert this string back into the `Data` representation ?

What I've tried so far is

```swift
let tokenString = "cd414ecaf22687b31b602cec11c7c4d797ead5cfece5fc59321e7ac35e36d4c1"
let tokenData = Data(tokenString.utf8)

// 63643431346563616632323638376233316236303263656331316337633464373937656164356366656365356663353933323165376163333565333664346331
let decodedDataBackToString = tokenData.map { String(format: "%02.2hhx", $0) }.joined()
```

Comment: If *this SDK wants the Data representation* why do you convert it to String at all?

Comment: Because I don't want to call the SDK right away

Comment: But why don't you *save this token for later use* as Data?

Comment: I'm using React Native and sending the String to RN, so that I later on can call back to a Swift class with the token. I don't think I can send a Data representation back to RN. Do you think its possible to turn the string back to the Data representation ?